# asp.net core 3 identity generatePasswordResetTokenAsync causes internal error

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I have setup the following code:

```
[HttpPost("requestPasswordReset")]
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<IActionResult> requestPasswordReset(UserNameDto userNameDto)
{
    var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(userNameDto.Username);

     if (user != null)

    {   
       var code = await _userManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user);
      return Ok(true);
    } 
  return Ok(false);
```

`var code = await _userManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user)` code returns an internal error with no more information.
Could someone help?

Comment: You should add the message from the error. It probably explains what the problem is. Perhaps the user doesn't have a password, check: `_UserManager.HasPasswordAsync(user)`

Comment: We need more info here, error log would really much help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for startup.cs;

```
 services.AddIdentity<User, UserRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

I wonder if it is as above